# Change list width to window size

Tags: html, css, list, css-float

I created a horizontal menu-bar by using `float: left;` style on every item in the list.
When I re-size my browser screen they will stack up vertically and mess up my layout. Is is possible to change their width's instead?

EDIT

List:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul class="menu nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="first-tab">Startpagina</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Historiek</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Bestuur</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Jeugdwerking</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Ploegen</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>ActiviteitenKalender</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Pers</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Wegbeschrijving</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Foto Albums</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Uitslagen(Archief)</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Uitslagen regioploegen(Archief)</span></a></li>
    </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#menu li {
z-index: 9;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 5px 0 0;
display: block;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer any of your questions if you do not post some code.

Comment: Google for "fluid layout".

Comment: Thanks Fransisco, That actually helped me out alot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the list items to `display: inline-block`?

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/upawih/1/edit)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

div#menu{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div#menu li {
z-index: 9;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 5px 0 0;
display: inline-block;

}
```